# How do I convince readers to keep reading poems with fixed rhyme?

Tags: publishing, editing, self-publishing, poetry

*Disclaimer: English isn't my native language and I haven't studied writing or poetry at all.*

I released my first poetry book called ["Bella Poesía / Beatiful Poetry"](http://www.autoreseditores.com/libro/2429/mauricio-arias-olave/bella-poesia.html) in February last year, and until recently I have been receiving feedback and reviews. However, I find it difficult to attract more readers and potential buyers due to (according to their comments) the fixed rhyme in the first poems available in the preview at the beginning of the book.

The rest of my book also contains different poems with different rhymes (not available in the preview) and on average, each month I'm updating my book with more and various poems. My book is dedicated to all women, and is "inspired by them" and all people who want to read and share poetry (even if they're infrequent or occasional readers).

*My main goal is for anyone with or without knowledge of poetry to be able to read and enjoy my book.*

With this in mind and like the title says: **How do I convince readers to keep reading poems with fixed rhyme?**

Comment: If the fixed-rhyme poems are a problem, why not move them to later in the book? See if you sell more copies.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: I'll do that. Thanks _I'll also check if in meta.writers_ I can extend my question for asking help about editing _I'm open for suggestions and new answers/comments._

Updated: [meta about book editing](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/958/are-questions-about-sources-or-references-for-help-book-editing-acceptable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poetry is a difficult to find an audience for regardless of what type of poetry it is. There's a lot of stigma regarding it.

I would put out poetry that you're proud of, and ignore the comments that tell you not to use a certain style: write what you're comfortable and proud of. Every poet has their own voice and style, and that's what should stand out, now which formats they use most prevalently.

I would also recommend doing poetry readings or posting videos of yourself reading your work online. Poetry is as much an audible experience as it is a visual one, and some poems can develop whole new meanings and layers to them when read aloud, *especially* when read by their writer.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 by your point of view and great positive answer. I'm actually in some poetry social networks, I received great comments and I'll try the _reading poetry_ Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even the most famous and celebrated poets tend to have limited audiences --and you'll never please everyone.  Given that, the most important thing is that you produce a book that you are proud of and happy with.

Comment: I would like read some of the most famous and celebrated poets that you may quote in your answer, however, I give +1 for your positive answer.

Comment: Well, consider my own favorite contemporary poet, Billy Collins, a former poet laureate of the United States.  His new poetry book is 45000 on the list of top bestselling books on amazon. http://www.amazon.com/Aimless-Love-New-Selected-Poems/dp/0812982673/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1422289068&sr=1-1&keywords=billy+collins

Comment: On the other hand "I could pee on this, and other poems by cats" is around #2000 on the amazon bestsellers list, so...